# Can I compare correlations even though one is NOT significant?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have 2 groups and 2 correlation coefficients that I would like to compare using Fisher's transformation. Unfortunately, one of these coefficents is not significant, so not different from zero.

Can I still perform the transformation because "not different from zero" does not mean "not different from the other coefficent"? Or is this "illegal" because a not significant correlation can not be interpreted?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can compare.

And where did you get the idea that a not-significant correlation can't be interpreted?

Nor does "not significant" mean "not different from 0".

"Not significant" means the following and nothing more:

**If, in the population from which this sample was taken, the true correlation was 0, it would not be unlikely to get a correlation as large as this**

Any correlation that is not 0 is different from 0.